# modifying css display through asp.net controls

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net-2010

Ok so I am trying to get a drop down menu to unhide some divs that I have hidden when a particular index is selected. I know that the inline style will need to be changed but have no clue how to use the back side controls to execute it.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"
CodeBehind="Estimation.aspx.vb" Inherits="CIS212FinalProjectASPportion.WebForm1" %>
<body Id="mainBody" runat="server">
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div id="EstimationSelection">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                <asp:ListItem>Select Value</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Lawn Care</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Plowing</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Both</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
</div>

<div id="UserInfo" style="display: none;">
    <asp:Label ID="firstName" runat="server" Text="Label">First Name &nbsp;</asp:Label>
    <input id="Text1" type="text" />
    <asp:Label ID="lastName" runat="server" Text="Label">Last Name &nbsp;</asp:Label>
    <input id="Text2" type="text" /> <br />
    <asp:Label ID="address" runat="server" Text="Label">Address       &nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</asp:Label>
    <input id="Text3" type="text" />
    <asp:Label ID="city" runat="server" Text="Label">City &nbsp;</asp:Label>
    <input id="Text4" type="text" /><br />
    <asp:Label ID="state" runat="server" Text="Label">State&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</asp:Label>
    <input id="Text5" type="text" />
    <asp:Label ID="zipCode" runat="server" Text="Label">Zip Code &nbsp;</asp:Label>
    <input id="Text6" type="text" /> <br />
    <asp:Label ID="emailAddress" runat="server" Text="Label">Email Address &nbsp;</asp:Label>
    <input id="Text7" type="text" />
</div>
</body>
</asp:Content>
```

Then right now for the backside code I have

```
Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If DropDownList1.SelectedIndex(1) Then
         Me.Body.Div.UserInfo.Style.add("display", "block")
        ' set div id="LawnCare" style="display: block;"
    End If
End Sub
```

Option Explicit and Strict are both on.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this..........

```
Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
  Dim oPanel As Panel
  oPanel = Me.FindControl("UserInfo")
  If DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
    oPanel.Visible = True
  Else
    oPanel.Visible = False
  End If
  oPanel = Nothing
End Sub


<div id="EstimationSelection">
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem>Select Value</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Lawn Care</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Plowing</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Both</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
  <br />
</div>

<asp:Panel id="UserInfo" Visible="false" runat="server">
  <asp:Label ID="firstName" runat="server" Text="Label">First Name</asp:Label>
    <input id="Text1" type="text" />
  <asp:Label ID="lastName" runat="server" Text="Label">Last Name</asp:Label>
    <input id="Text2" type="text" /> <br />
  <asp:Label ID="address" runat="server" Text="Label">Address</asp:Label>
    <input id="Text3" type="text" />
  <asp:Label ID="city" runat="server" Text="Label">City</asp:Label>
    <input id="Text4" type="text" /><br />
  <asp:Label ID="state" runat="server" Text="Label">State</asp:Label>
    <input id="Text5" type="text" />
  <asp:Label ID="zipCode" runat="server" Text="Label">Zip Code</asp:Label>
    <input id="Text6" type="text" /> <br />
  <asp:Label ID="emailAddress" runat="server" Text="Label">Email Address</asp:Label>
    <input id="Text7" type="text" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Basically I changed your clientside DIV to a serverside PANEL